# Why i keep getting exception after added checkBoxes in index 0 before column1 in dataGridView1?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In top of form1 i did:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chk;
```

In constructor:

```
chk = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
dataGridView1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

Then i have this method i call it from a timer tick event every 5 seconds:
The method add rows to the dataGridView1 according to how many processes are running:
In this method i also call the method that add the checkBoxes:

```
void PopulateApplications()
        {
            DoubleBufferedd(dataGridView1, true);



                int rcount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
                int rcurIndex = 0;
                foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
                {

                        try
                        {
                            if (File.Exists(p.MainModule.FileName))
                            {


                                        var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(p.MainModule.FileName);
                                        Image ima = icon.ToBitmap();
                                        ima = resizeImage(ima, new Size(25, 25));
                                        ima = (Image)(new Bitmap(ima, new Size(25, 25)));
                                        String status = p.Responding ? "Running" : "Not Responding";
                                        if (rcurIndex < rcount - 1)
                                        {
                                            dataGridView1.Rows[rcurIndex].Cells[0].Value = ima;
                                            dataGridView1.Rows[rcurIndex].Cells[1].Value = p.ProcessName;
                                            dataGridView1.Rows[rcurIndex].Cells[2].Value = status;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(ima, p.ProcessName, status);
                                        }
                                        rcurIndex++;



                            }
                        }
                        catch ( Exception e)
                        {
                            string t = "error";
                        }
                }

                if (rcurIndex < rcount - 1)
                {
                    for (int i = rcurIndex; i < rcount - 1; i++)
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(rcurIndex);
                    }
                }


            int f = dataGridView1.Rows.GetRowsHeight(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewElementStates.None);
            firsttime += 1;
            if (firsttime == 1)
            {
                NumberOfRows = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
                AddCheckBox();
            }
            if (NumberOfRows != dataGridView1.Rows.Count)
            {
                int diff = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - NumberOfRows;
                NumberOfRows = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
            }



        }
```

The problem is when im calling this method from PopulateApplications() method that add checkBoxes on the left side before the first column1 in the dataGridView1:

```
private void AddCheckBox()
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, chk);
            chk.HeaderText = "Check Data";
            chk.Name = "chk";

        }
```

Once i'm adding this checkBoxes im getting this exception popup every 5 seconds:

[image]

Why i'm getting this exception after adding the checkBoxes ?

If i don't call this method that add checkBoxes i don't get any exception/s.
I tried to call the method AddCheckBox() from the form1 constructor but then there are no any rows yet so i'm getting error. That's why i call the AddCheckBox method through the PopulateApplications() method.

EDIT

Changed the code in the method to:

```
if (rcurIndex < rcount - 1)
                                        {
                                            var currentRow = dataGridView1.Rows[rcurIndex];
                                            currentRow.Cells[0].Value = true;  // or false for unchecked
                                            currentRow.Cells[1].Value = ima;
                                            currentRow.Cells[2].Value = p.ProcessName;
                                            currentRow.Cells[3].Value = status;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(true, ima, p.ProcessName, status);
                                        }
                                        rcurIndex++;
```

Now im getting this exception:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see where you add the initial `DataGridView` columns, but from the following code:

```
if (rcurIndex < rcount - 1)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[rcurIndex].Cells[0].Value = ima;
    dataGridView1.Rows[rcurIndex].Cells[1].Value = p.ProcessName;
    dataGridView1.Rows[rcurIndex].Cells[2].Value = status;
}
else
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(ima, p.ProcessName, status);
}
```

It would appear you have three columns to start with - an Image or Bitmap, and then two strings.

But then you insert a `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` (boolean) before the existing columns.

Now when you execute the above code, it's going to try shoving the Bitmap value in the CheckBox column, then the first string value in the Bitmap column, etc.

I'm not sure what to suggest since I can't exactly tell what you intend to do with the CheckBox, but you need to modify the above code to insert a boolean value (checked or unchecked) into that column first, once it's been added to the `DataGridView`.

```
if (rcurIndex < rcount - 1)
{
    var currentRow = dataGridView1.Rows[rcurIndex];
    currentRow.Cells[0].Value = true;  // or false for unchecked
    currentRow.Cells[1].Value = ima;
    currentRow.Cells[2].Value = p.ProcessName;
    currentRow.Cells[3].Value = status;
}
else
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(true, ima, p.ProcessName, status);
}
```

Comment: Grant tried your solution now im getting another exception just when running the program connecting with the boolean. Updated my question with the exception.